# IIS caching of static files is not reflecting modified date of files on disk

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

Our web application is using ASP.NET MVC 4, running on Windows Server 2008R2 Datacenter and IIS 7.5.

We have a custom HttpModule for URL rewriting.  Some of the URLs that end up getting rewritten are serving static files on disk, for example incoming URL (paths are fake but you get it): 
/media/virtual/mystatic.html
gets remapped to:
/iis/virtual/directory/mystatic.html

These static files can also be created by the application.  For example, a request is made, and a log file is created, and the URL to the log is returned in the response with a [202](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202).  The intention is for the client to be able to open up the log file in the browser, and refresh it to see progress being made as the requested task is executed and updates are made to the log file on the server.

But what we're seeing is that the log file is opened on the client, and *even though it is being updated on the server*, the browser continues to show the file as it was first created, without any updates!

We've been wrestling with this for several months now, and **have already implemented the following to try to resolve it**:

- In IIS, we've edited the Cache Control header, checked "Expire Web content", and selected Immediately.  Request and Response headers for these requests show Cache-Control: no-cache
- In IIS, we've updated Output Caching and UN-checked both "Enable cache" and "Enable kernel cache"
- We've removed ETag headers altogether using an HttpModule

**When the issue occurs, we've noted the following**:

- RDPing into the server, if we open the file in a browser on the server using a file:// URL the updated version will be displayed.  Opening it in another tab of the same browser on the server with an http:// URL will show the (improperly cached) NON-updated version!
- Recycling the Application Pool will 'refresh' the file and show the updated version to all clients

With all of these updates/notes, it seems pretty certain to me that the caching is still happening at an IIS level.  What else can we do here???  When we write to the file, is there a way (in ASP.NET/C#) to force IIS to see the updates?  Is there an IIS caching setting that we're missing?

Help.  Much appreciate your time.

Comment: Instead of trying to deal with caching and file locking from write or read, use SignalR with NLog to show the file in real time to the browser as HTML. this will also allow you to use events to log the output to the clients data records showing the task has been complete. There are many ways to do what you are trying to do but with out seeing how you are serving the log file it is hard to help with what is going on.

Comment: I appreciate the reference and will certainly look into SignalR.  But it seems like there should be a way to tell IIS "always serve files from the file system, and never cache them"?